# Function continuity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

I am given:

> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> x^{4/3}\sin(1/x)  & \text{if $x\neq0$} \\
> 0 & \text{if $x=0$}  \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

I need to show that

1. $f$ is cts on $\mathbb{R}$
2. $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$
3. $f'(x)$ is unbounded on any open interval containing 0.

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Continuity and differentiability on $\mathbb{R}^*$ are obvious. For continuity at $0$, show $\lim_0 f=0$, and for differentiability at $0$, show $\lim_0 f(x)/x=0$. Each time using $|\sin |\leq 1$. For 3, try to plug $x_n=1/n\pi$ in the derivative.

Comment: hmmm, i'm sorry, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: For 1, can you see that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^*$ and that continuity at $0$ amounts to $\lim_0f=0$? If so, what would you do to prove the latter? Hint: squeeze.

Comment: I see what you mean for continuity, but how can I be sure that the fcn is differentiable everywhere (including 0)?

Comment: It is clearly differentiable outside of $0$, right? Then at $0$, apply the definition and compute $\lim_0(f(x)-f(0)/(x-0)$. That is $\lim_0 f(x)/x$. Show that this is $0$, which by def means that $f$ is diff at $0$ with $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: ok i follow you, thanks. It is enough in a formal proof to say that f is clearly diff outside of 0, then proceed to examine the 0 case as you have described?

Comment: @jdh8 Yes, it is. And $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, you can treat the nozero case in a second. But give the derivative, it is probably better. ANd you need it for 3.

Comment: great thanks a lot, much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is  clearly continuous for $x\neq 0$ because $ x^{4/3}\sin(1/x)$ is continuous. Since $$-x^{4/3}\leq x^{4/3}\sin(1/x)\leq x^{4/3}$$ by the squeeze thorem $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^{4/3}\sin(1/x) = 0$$ so $f$ is also continuous for $x=0$.

Similarly, $f$ is clearly differentiable at any $x\neq 0$, for $x=0$ use the definition of the derivative to get \begin{eqnarray*}f'(0)& =& \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \\&=& \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}\\
&=&\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^{4/3}\sin(1/h)}{h}\\
&=&\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h^{1/3}\sin(1/h)\\
&=&0\end{eqnarray*}

so $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and we have 
$$f'(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}4/3x^{1/3}\sin(1/x) + x^{4/3}\cos(1/x)(-\frac{1}{x^2}) & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0\end{array}\right.$$

Now notice that the term $|x^{4/3}\cos(1/x)(-\frac{1}{x^2})|$ grows unboundedly when $x$ goes to $0$. So the same is true for $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The continuity and differentiability of $f$ on $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ follows immediately. Note, $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(x^{4/3}\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)=0=f(0)$$ $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(x^{1/3}\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$$since $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{4/3}=\lim_{x\to 0}x^{1/3}=0$ and $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is bounded in any deleted neighborhood of $0.$ Consequently $f$ is continuous and differentiable at $0.$